# Can I make custom bokeh shape using a 18-55mm Nikkor lens?

Tags: aperture, nikon-d5100, bokeh, shaped-bokeh

Custom bokeh shapes need a large aperture. The max aperture my lens can reach is `f3.5`. Is it big enough for a custom bokeh? I tried but it doesn't work.

Comment: Note that you'll get more apparent blur at the tele end of your zoom, even though the f number is larger. So you should try at 55mm f5.6 rather than 18mm f3.5.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Though you may have to fiddle with your camera settings a bit to achieve it.

I did this once with that lens on a D3100. You will need to shoot wide open of course. Also zooming into your subject will make the depth of field shallower, which you will need to do for this type of bokeh on this lens.

Also the size of the custom shape cutout is important. If you cut the shape out too large for the aperture settings that you use, it will not give you the full shape in the boheh. However don't make the cutout too small either.
Hope this helps!

Comment: See [What size hole do I use to make differently shaped bokeh?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/9549/what-size-hole-do-i-use-to-make-differently-shaped-bokeh) for more on that last point.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible but presumably you are talking about the aperture shapes in the out of focus area?

If that's what you want then you need to make sure that this area is well outside the focus area that you subject is in.

A good way to test is to lower your aperture, go outside where you have some street lights and manually focus the lens, you should see the shapes around the lights.