# How to do custom bokeh on Nikon D3200 with 18-55mm lens (f3.5)?

Tags: lighting, aperture, bokeh, nikon-d3200

I am attempting to use custom bokeh for an effect in which words appear in out of focus lights. After many experimentations i still can't manage to get it to work, i believe this is largely because of my aperture?

I would be so grateful for some advice as this would look great in a film I'm making.

Comment: Changing the iso, size of the shape, different light sources in different positions of the frame etc. Most of the tutorials and blogposts i have seen are for lens with around f1.8 in aperture so i assume that i need a different lens that can go to a wider aperture.

Comment: What results are you getting with that? [How can I get dramatic shallow DOF with a kit lens?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/5493/how-can-i-get-dramatic-shallow-dof-with-a-kit-lens) may help with the general technique, although it doesn't cover shaped bokeh.

Comment: Looks like this is the same question as [Can I make custom bokeh shape using a 18-55mm Nikkor lens?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/50107/can-i-make-custom-bokeh-shape-using-a-18-55mm-nikkor-lens)

Comment: there seems to be no change in shape whatsoever, yes i looked at that question however need more elaboration as i am still struggling.

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention anything about what your process is. Are you sticking something between the lens and the sensor? If you can elaborate on what you're doing, that would help.

Regardless, to get the effect and have it be visible, you should have a wide aperture, focus on something fairly close to the lens, and have the lights be far away and bright. Here are some tests shots I took while trying to learn to use a tilt-shift lens that had a replaceable aperture:

Focused close, far away lights show strong bokeh:
[image]

Focused farther away, far away lights show less strong bokeh:
[image]

Comment: I have been placing a piece of card with a shape cut out into it in front of the lens. I have been trying to get shots of my christmas tree today from a distance in a close focus but still have no results.

Comment: Maybe you could try photographing something outside, where you can get significantly farther away and see if you are able to get any good results? That would tell you if distance is the issue. You might also try with a couple of different cut outs of different sizes to see how that affects things. Perhaps a smaller or larger cut-out would produce better results?

Comment: Yes, i think i will just have to keep experimenting with your suggestions. Thank you for all your help though!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the cutouts you have been using might not be small enough to actually block much light that would actually make it through the aperture of the lens. In this case the light your cutout is blocking is light that wouldn't be in the photo even if the cutout were not there, sort of like what a lens hood does.

Try using a smaller pattern to see if that will affect your pictures more. Then focus very close with the lights you want to blur into each other as far away from the camera as is possible.